# Boole[] returns non-numerical value?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find the maximum value $t$ such that my function $h$ is bigger than $t$ on (at least) half of the interval $[0,2\pi]$ and smaller than $t$ on the other half, i.e.: $$ \text{sup}\{t\in \mathbb{R} : \lambda(\{ x\in [0, 2\pi]: h(x)\geq t\})>\pi\}.$$

In my case, the function $h$ is the integral of the difference between two other functions, $f$ and $g$. I am trying to calculate the length of the interval where $h(x) \geq t$ by integrating a Boolean. I have tried the following:

```
Clear[f, g, h, q];
f[x_?NumericQ] = Sum[(1 - Abs[k]/6)*E^(I*k*(x - (Pi/3))), {k, -5, 5}];
g[x_?NumericQ] = Sum[(1 - Abs[k]/6)*E^(I*k*(x - (5*Pi/3))), {k, -5, 5}];
h[t_?NumericQ] = Integrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, 0, t}]/(2*Pi);
q[z_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] = Boole[Chop[h[v]] <= Chop[h[z]]];
FindMaxValue[{Chop[h[z]], (Integrate[q[z, v], {v, 0, 2*Pi}]) >= Pi}, z]
```

Now I am getting the following errors:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand q[1.,v] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,6.28319}}.

> General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation.

> FindMaxValue::nrlnum: The function value {-[Pi]+!(*SubsuperscriptBox[([Integral]), (0), (2\ [Pi])](q[1.`, v] [DifferentialD]v))} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {1} at {z} = {1.}.

I guess that the problem is that Mathematica is trying to evaluate q[1,v] which indeed is not a number. How do I get Mathematica to integrate this right?

Comment: Concerning your last remark, what the error message is telling you is that it evaluated things like `q[1., 2.]` and didn't get a number. (Here `2.` represents one of the sampling points and may not be one of the actual values for `v` it used.)  If you evaluate `q[1., 2.]` you will get another clue about what is going wrong.

Comment: May you please clarify what “on half of the interval” mean? The formula expresses “on at least half of the interval” instead.

Comment: When the function h is continuous and nowhere constant, then the t I'm looking for will be such that h is larger than t on exactly half the interval. But you're right, it's not the same in general so I edited my question slightly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case,

- `?NumericQ` condition is not necessary in function definitions, but
- `?NumericQ` is needed for `NIntegrate` (ref. [the documentation for message](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NIntegrate/inumr.html.en)), so the integral should be split off, here to `lambda[z_?NumericQ]`:

  - using `:=` for evaluation to happen only when arguments are passed in.

```
ClearAll[f, g, h, q, lambda];
f[x_] = Sum[(1 - Abs[k]/6)*E^(I*k*(x - (Pi/3))), {k, -5, 5}];
g[x_] = Sum[(1 - Abs[k]/6)*E^(I*k*(x - (5*Pi/3))), {k, -5, 5}];
h[t_] = Integrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, 0, t}]/(2*Pi) // FullSimplify // N;
q[z_, v_] := Boole[Chop[h[v]] <= Chop[h[z]]]
lambda[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[q[z, v], {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
FindMaximum[{Chop[h[z]], 0 <= z <= 2 Pi && lambda[z] > Pi}, {z, Pi}]
```

> `{0.8821262327, {z -> 3.141592654}}`

Comment: Sorry @SneezeFor16Min and @Evert-JanHekkelman, this can not be true. You simply get the total maximium of function h[t]. `Plot[{0.8821262327, h[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}] ` to see this.

Comment: @Akku14 On reviewing the question, it seems that $\sup\{t:\lambda(t)>\pi\}$ doesn't correspond to what OP said above, which should be $\sup\{t:\lambda(t)=\pi\}$, exactly half. Otherwise $t_0$ with $\lambda(t_0)=2\pi$ is accepted and thus $h(t_0)$ becomes the simple maximum.

Comment: Changing the last line to ```FindMaximum[{Chop[h[z]], 0 <= z <= 2 Pi && lambda[z] < Pi}, z]``` works! That returns ```{0.808616, {z -> 1.5708}}```, which is correct.

Comment: Then @Akku14 's interpretation and answer are also correct. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

I interpreted: "I am trying to find the maximum value h[ts]
such that my function h is bigger than h[ts] on half of the interval [0,2π] and smaller than h[ts] on the other half, i.e.:"

```
f[x_] = Sum[(1 - Abs[k]/6)*E^(I*k*(x - (Pi/3))), {k, -5, 5}];
g[x_] = Sum[(1 - Abs[k]/6)*E^(I*k*(x - (5*Pi/3))), {k, -5, 5}];
h[t_] = Integrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, 0, t}]/(2*Pi) // FullSimplify

(*   (4*(35 + 40*Cos[t] + 13*Cos[2*t] + 2*Cos[3*t])*
  Sin[t/2]^4)/(5*Sqrt[3]*Pi)   *)

{p1, p2} = {t1, t2} /. 
  First@Solve[{h[t2] == h[t1], t2 - t1 == Pi, 0 < t1 < Pi}, {t1, t2},
  Reals] // FullSimplify

(*   {Pi/2, (3*Pi)/2}   *)

Plot[{h[Pi/2], h[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Epilog -> Point@{{p1, h[p1]}, {p2, h[p2]}}
]
```

[image]

**Edit**   Extension for functions with more humps.

Use UnitStep and provide the exact zeros of h[t]- hs (hs searched for) to get better integration results.

```
nsol[hs_?NumericQ] := 
  t /. NSolve[
  0 < t < 2 Pi &&   TrigExpand[h[t] - hs] == 0, t
]

nint[hs_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[UnitStep[h[t] - hs], 
  Evaluate[Flatten[{t, 0, nsol[hs], 2 Pi}]]]

FindRoot[nint[hs] == Pi, {hs, .7}]

(*   {hs -> 0.808616}   *)

h[Pi/2] // N[#, 15] &

(*   0.808615713285295   *)
```

Comment: That's a clever workaround, thanks for the idea! I am new to Mathematica and trying to learn, and I am wondering if you know a way to do such a thing if the function has more than one hump? Or would that become a complicated undertaking?

Comment: @Evert-JanHekkelman  please see my edit.